# use of Parameters<this['method']> fails

Tags: typescript

```
class Example { 
  alpha(props: { check: boolean }) { 
    // noop
  }

  beta(props:
    Partial<Parameters<this['alpha']>[0]> // this fails
    // Partial<Parameters<Example['alpha']>[0]> // this works
    // Partial<{ check: boolean }> // this works
  ) { 
    // noop
  }

  useBeta(props:
    { check?: boolean | undefined }
  ) { 
    const { check } = props
    return this.beta({ check })
  }

}
```

I've been using `this` to reference methods input parameters, but I found a case where it's not working, and I wanted to document it / get some thoughts behind why this case doesn't work.

Comment: At 35k I would expect you to know that debugging help is required to include the specific error rather than "this fails". Could you please update the question?

Answer (score 1):

I would just extract `{check: boolean}` to some interface and pass it along. Anyway that was not a question. The question is why it does not work with `this`.

Compiler can not guarantee that `this` is going to be `Example` instance. Compiler only can guarantee that `this` is going to be of pseudo-generic `<T extends Example>` type.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification

---

(*Updated: initial answer was totally wrong.*)

Comment: It was also my first thought, but actually only the "Partial" part doesn't work here for some reason. Also if it was the consideration - type checking for `this` wouldn't work at all

Comment: Your are right. `this` can be used as type. But it is special type:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types

Comment: Again, only partial part doesn't work. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvaAoa0YIKAFmABQoBOA9ihAFzbTAnrADWTARjTRmAB20AL4BKZvgLQA9DOiC+KKSNxTu6AC4VqdRtAAKYKsi3oqEADyaSASwgBtAORFSYJwF0AfA4AMHsRwVNQIAVwh0ACEtHVp6JhxWdi5oXn50IVEJIOkWGkEITWYkzlFoAF5oXXopAiotUKphG3sAOg1tckS2UvFgkSA)

Comment: You are right again. I am giving up. It seems that it is a bug in compiler.